# Core Data issue - optional type when shouldn't be

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on Core Data in swift, the tutorial seems to be from an older version of swift and i've started running into errors, that the video poster wasn't

The following is written exactly the same, but i'm getting errors:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell =  tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell
    //error: operand of postfix '?' should have optional type: type is uitableview.

    if let ip = indexPath {
        var data: NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("username")
        //UILabel? does not have a member named "text'
    }
    return cell
}
```

I've been stuck on this for an hour and am thinking of giving up. Has swift changed to the point where this can't be done like this

Comment: Follow the error messages. Looks like `tableView ` used to be an Optional but isn't anymore, so remove the `?` from `tableView?`. On the contrary, your textLabel seems to be an unwrapped Optional, so either unwrap it `cell.textLabel!.text` or better, use an `if let`.

Comment: yeah i'd already tried those things. Removing the '?' after tableView fixes that error, but i still have the same error for textLabel, even though its already in an if let. adding '!' doesn't help either

Comment: By "use an if let" I meant use it *on your textLabel*, like `if let myLabel = cell.textLabel`. You could also try with an `?` (for nil coalescing) like in Benson Tommy's answer. Oh, and you need the last Xcode version,of course, to follow with Swift syntax modifications.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID = "Cell"
    var cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as! UITableViewCell

    var data = myList[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKey("username") as? String

    return cell
}
```

Copy and replace your method with the above one,hope the compiler won't complain.

**[The code is written in Xcode 6.3(Swift 1.2)]**